# Unable to install Community Management Package

Tags: community, custom-report-type

Our org currently has only portals. I created a community to test and under "Community Management" it prompted me to install the "Communities Management Package" developed by Salesforce. When I try to install, it keeps throwing the following error:

[image]

We are using Enterprise edition which has a limit of 200 custom report types and our org currently has 166 custom report types. I'm able to install other packages, but this one keeps  throwing "Exceeded the maximum number of custom report types allowed" error. I'm trying to understand what is different with this package.

Comment: You can have maximum 200 custom report types in Enterprise edition. Seems, Community package is exceeding this limit due to which you are receiving an error at the time of Installation.

Comment: @Devendra Does it mean this package contains more than 34 custom report types?

Comment: Yes, I am able to install this package in my developer  org and checked the report type count. There are around 46 custom report types. For Developer org, the limit is 400.

Comment: @Devendra 46 custom report types? Huhh. Thank you for checking. I cannot understand why Developer Edition has 400 custom report types limit when Enterprise edition has only 200. Can you please move your comment to answer? I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have maximum 200 custom report types in Enterprise edition. Community package is exceeding this limit due to which you are receiving an error at the time of Installation.

Check [Salesforce Limit Document](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/19/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf)

[image]

You can also go through the below link to identify Community Package Components.

[Community Management Package Guide](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P3A00000UefznUAB)

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Communities Management (for Communities with Chatter) managed package from the AppExchange contains 46 Custom Report Types in the Summmer 16 version, which appears to be the current version.

As a managed package it is not possible to change the components, but if you wish to install it and were able to reduce the number of custom report types in your Org to 154 it would be possible.